# Partially Nested/Partially Crossed Model

Tags: r, nested, lme4

I've spent a fair amount of time searching and reading about partially nested/partially crossed models, especially as it applies to lmer, and none of the solutions I've find work as I'd like for a dataset I was handed to analyze.

The study has two substantive variables, primacy and positivity, and a message replication.  The positivity variable indicates the percentage of positively-valenced phrases in the message, which varies from 100% to 20%. Messages that have 100% positivity have no negative phrases.  The primacy condition indicates whether the negative phrase occurs first or last in the message. Messages with no negativity (100% positive) are the control for primacy, as there cannot be a primacy effect without negative message elements. Finally, each cell in the positivity*primacy table has 2 versions of the message, which is standard procedure in message effects designs (although ideally there would be more than 2 versions of a given message). The DV is a rating (1 to 5) on the message's effectiveness.

I include a table of the design below:

[image: study design]

EDIT: Here's an inelegant way to provide reproducible data. I've simplified the example by excluding the 40% and 20% levels of positivity.

```
 set.seed(1234)
 df <- data.frame(primacy = c(rep("control",18),rep("first",18), rep("last",18)), 
                 positivity = rep(c(rep("100%",3),rep("80%",3),rep("60%",3)),6),
                 message = as.factor(rep(1:18, times=1, each=9)),
                 dv = round(runif(162,0,5), 0))

#delete cases that contain "wrong" combinations of factors
(df %>%
  mutate(dv = ifelse(primacy == "control" & positivity != "100%", NA, dv),
         dv = ifelse(primacy != "control" & positivity == "100%", NA, dv),
         message = ifelse(message == 7 | message == 8, 1, message),
         message = ifelse(message == 13 | message == 14, 2, message)) %>%
    na.omit) -> df1


with(df1, ftable(message, primacy, positivity))

model <- lme4::lmer(dv ~ primacy/positivity + (1|message), data=df1)

summary(model)
anova(model)
emmeans::lsmeans(model, ~positivity)
```

From what I see, positivity is partially nested or partially crossed with primacy. The 100% positivity condition occurs only in the primacy control condition, and the other positivity conditions are crossed with the P (negativity first) and R (negativity last) primacy conditions, but not with the control.

The question is how to specify the model in `lmer`. Message version is the random effect (differences in message versions are not of substantive interest), and primacy and positivity are the fixed effects. Positivity seems nested within primacy, which means `lmer` should be:

```r
 lmer(effective ~ primacy/positivity + (1|version), 
                 data=df, REML=T)
```

The anova output shows a main effect for primacy and the interaction between primacy and positivity, but no main effect for positivity.  I suspect the design precludes estimation of the main effect for positivity.

EDIT: Axeman is correct--lmer drops the columns that are "empty".

It would greatly simplify things to drop the primacy control condition, which is estimated with:

```r
lmer(effective ~ primacy*positivity + (1|version), 
                 data=df, REML=T)
```

Doing so, however, loses the comparison of the primacy control condition with the other two levels of that variable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A small reproducible dataset (not the actual data, just a representation of it) would be helpful.

Comment: Hi Felix.  Yes, they generally are.  Trying to put one together.

Comment: Seems to me that you can fit the latter model, as non-existing combinations will be dropped by `lmer`. `primacy/positivity` doesn't show a main effect of positivity because that is explicitly what the `/` is used to do, `a/b` is expanded into `a + a:b`.